# How many ways we can access user's location iOS?

Tags: ios, location

I know we can access user's location using geolocation in iOS. I want to know what other ways we can access user's location off course with his permission. I also heard we can access user's location using network/Internet etc.

Answer (score 2):

All geolocation of the device is done via the CoreLocation framework.  The specifics of what method(s) used to determine the location is not provided through the framework.  The position can be determined via WiFi proximity to a known AP, cellular proximity to a tower mapped by the carrier, or most accurately via the GPS system.  Not all methods are available on all devices, obviously.  Rather than knowing how location was determined, you merely request location within a desired level of accuracy, and the framework will call back and notify you of an update in position.  The actual position is not guaranteed to be pinpoint accurate.